# ¿Cómo puedo generar e insertar automáticamente el id desde php?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy tipeando y guardando el id de forma manual desde el `input`, pero necesito autogenerar el código y que inserte automáticamente. Sin usar el `autoincremet` de `mysql`, alguien me puede ayudar por favor. La parte del `input` el `name` y `id` son usados en agregar.php, código que esta mas abajo.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>CODIGO</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigovista" id="p0">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Javascript:

```
//boton guardar 
    $('#guardar').on('click', function(){
        var v0 = $('#p0').val();
        var v1 = $('#p1').val();
        var v2 = $('#p2').val();
        var v3 = $('#p3').val(); //------------------------------
        var v4 = $('#p4').val(); 
        var v5 = $('#p5').val(); 
        if (v0.length>0 && v1.length>0 && v2.length>0 && v3.length>0 && v4.length>0 && v5.length>0)
```

Agregar.php, los valores son llamados en el js:

```
$p0 = $_POST['codigovista'];
$p1 = $_POST['razonsocialvista'];
$p2 = $_POST['rucvista'];
$p3 = $_POST['fechavista'];
$p4 = $_POST['comentariovista'];
$p5 = $_POST['estadovista'];
$conexion->add($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3,$p4,$p5);
```

Insert:

```
public function add($v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5)
{
    //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contribuyentes VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    //parametro a statement
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$v0,$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5);
    //ejecutar el query
    $stmt->execute();
    //cerrar statement
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Tabla de la bd:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo lo haria con un procedimiento almacenado, tomando el max id de la tabla obviamente validas si es null y  haces la logica.

Answer (score 1):

porque no realizas una sentencia, donde tomas el valor maximo del id de la tabla. y le sumas 1 al nuevo. y asi sucesivamente.

```
 select id =(isnull( max(id), 0)  + 1 ) from contribuyentes 


|id|
 1 -- la primera vez
```

y le sumo el resultado a mi id de entrada.
en este caso supongo que tu id es la variable que contiene.

```
$p0 = $_POST['codigovista'];
```

en este caso seria. algo asi.

```
   //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('select id =(isnull( max(id), 0)  + 1 ) from contribuyentes');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// aqui obtienes el id a guardar
    $idNew = $result->id;
```

espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda , ya esta solucionado.